# FlatFileHeaderCallback usage in case of dynamic queries

Tags: spring-batch

I have a Spring Batch application which reads from DB and writes to a CSV file. CSV file needs a header which one can provide using the **FlatFileHeaderCallback** interface in **FlatFileItemWriter** of Spring Batch. The problem is the query to read data from database is dynamic hence the columns are not fixed hence I cannot hard code the column names in the interface.

The reader has a rowmapper to dynamically read the data of every row using a sql injected using the jobparameters. I thought of caching the columnnames here and then using the cached rows in the interface. However, this is called after the `FlatFileItemWriter` calls the `doOpen` where it calls the `this.headerCallback.writeHeader(outputState.outputBufferedWriter)` so I cant cache the column names and then somehow  write the header row in the callback.

One solution is that I maintain a flag somewhere and then change its state once I have written the header row in the csv in the writer when the writer is called for the first time.

Please find below the complete jobconfiguration with this idea :
Please note I am injecting the SQL in the `jdbcCursorItemReader` bean as an argument using SPEL like so `@Value("#{jobParameters['sql']}"`.

```
@Slf4j
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class OracleToSFTPJobConfig {

    @Qualifier("transactionManager")
    @Autowired
    PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager;


    @Bean("csvJob")
    public Job oracleToSFTPJob(Step oracleToCsvStep, Step move, JobRepository jobRepository) {

        return new JobBuilder("oracleToSFTPJob", jobRepository)
                .start(oracleToCsvStep)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step oracleToCsvStep(JdbcCursorItemReader<Row> jdbcCursorItemReader,
                                 FlatFileItemWriter<Row> csvItemWriter, JobRepository jobRepository) {

        return new StepBuilder("oracleToCsvStep", jobRepository)
                .<Row, Row>chunk(2, transactionManager)
                .reader(jdbcCursorItemReader)
                .writer(csvItemWriter)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public JdbcCursorItemReader<Row> jdbcCursorItemReader(DataSource dataSource, RowMapper<Row> rowMapper, @Value("#{jobParameters['sql']}") final String sql, final ColumnNamesHolder columnNamesHolder) {
        JdbcCursorItemReader<Row> reader = new JdbcCursorItemReader<>();
        reader.setDataSource(dataSource);
        reader.setSql(sql);
        reader.setRowMapper(rowMapper(columnNamesHolder));
        return reader;
    }


    @Bean
    public RowMapper<Row> rowMapper(ColumnNamesHolder columnNamesHolder) {
        return (rs, rowNum) -> {
            log.info("Reading a row...{}", rowNum);
            ResultSetMetaData metaData = rs.getMetaData();
            int columnCount = metaData.getColumnCount();
            Map<String, Object> resultMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
            List<String> columnNames = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 1; i <= columnCount; i++) {
                String columnName = metaData.getColumnName(i);
                Object value = rs.getObject(i);
                resultMap.put(columnName, value);
                columnNames.add(columnName);
            }
            if(!columnNamesHolder.isHeaderWritten()) {
                columnNamesHolder.getColumnNames().addAll(columnNames);
            }
            return new Row(resultMap);
        };
    }

    @StepScope
    @Bean
    public FlatFileItemWriter<Row> sftpItemWriter(final ColumnNamesHolder columnNamesHolder) throws InterruptedException {
        FlatFileItemWriter<Row> writer = new CustomFlatFileItemWriter<>(columnNamesHolder);
        writer.setResource(new FileSystemResource("output-" + UUID.randomUUID().toString().substring(0, 3) +".csv"));
        writer.setLineAggregator(item -> {
            log.info("Delimiting rows...");
            return StringUtils.collectionToCommaDelimitedString(item.getDbRow().values());
        });
        return writer;
    }



    public static class CustomFlatFileItemWriter<T> extends FlatFileItemWriter {
        private final ColumnNamesHolder columnNamesHolder;


        public CustomFlatFileItemWriter(ColumnNamesHolder columnNamesHolder) {
            this.columnNamesHolder = columnNamesHolder;
        }

        @Override
        public String doWrite(Chunk items) {
            if(!columnNamesHolder.isHeaderWritten()) {
                try {
                    final StringBuilder header = new StringBuilder();
                    header.append(StringUtils.collectionToCommaDelimitedString(columnNamesHolder.getColumnNames()));
                    header.append(this.lineSeparator);
                    getOutputState().write(header.toString());
                    columnNamesHolder.setHeaderWritten(true);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            }

            return super.doWrite(items);
        }

        private static void await(long await) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(await);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
    }


    @Bean
    public TaskExecutor jobLauncherTaskExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(15);
        executor.setCorePoolSize(10);
        executor.setPrestartAllCoreThreads(true);
        return executor;
    }

    @Bean
    public JobLauncher jobLauncher(JobRepository jobRepository) throws Exception {
        TaskExecutorJobLauncher jobLauncher = new TaskExecutorJobLauncher();
        jobLauncher.setJobRepository(jobRepository);
        jobLauncher.setTaskExecutor(jobLauncherTaskExecutor());
        jobLauncher.afterPropertiesSet();
        return jobLauncher;
    }

    @Data
    public class ColumnNamesHolder {
        private ArrayList<String> columnNames = new ArrayList<>();
        private boolean headerWritten;
    }

    @JobScope
    @Bean
    public ColumnNamesHolder columnNamesHolder() {
        return new ColumnNamesHolder();
    }

}
```

This works but seems dirty to me. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You can use a step-scoped `FlatFileHeaderCallback` and inject the column into its definition. Where is the dynamism defined? Are dynamic columns passed as job parameters? System properties? Loaded from somewhere with a listener or a previous step and put in the execution context? This is key to correctly answer your question. Please share the code of that part.

Comment: The rowMapper (code already mentioned above) is where I can get the columns for the first time from the resultset generated after firing the SQL query. I cannot pass the columns themselves to job params or system props because the SQl query can be anything i.e. its not hardcoded. I pass the SQL query to the jobparams when I trigger the job. Although the SQL query can be different each time when the job is triggered I  I can parse the query to get the column names but then I would need to write sql parser which is not trivial. The reader for DB and the CSV writer are part of the same step

Comment: Thanks for the update. I see now, the columns are fetched from the ResultSet, but how is the query passed? Is it something like `select * from ...` ?

Comment: I pass the SQL query as a job parameter while triggering the job and inject it in the JdbcCursorItemReader bean as an argument like so : @Value("#{jobParameters['sql']}") final String sql

Comment: And yes it will always be a "Select query".

Comment: That's good. In that case, a better way than the current `ColumnNamesHolder` is to create a step-scoped header callback bean, in which you inject the columns from the job parameters as you did for the reader. Have you tried that? `And yes it will always be a "Select query"` I understand that, but the key point here since the columns are the dynamic part is that the query is like `select * ..` or `select column1, column2 ..`? You should know upfront what columns to query since you are passing the query as a job parameter right?

Comment: Ah ok. It will not be a "*" as its not allowed. So it may be column1, column2 or ```column1 as perferredColumn1Name, column2 as preferredColumn2Name``` or it could be ```a.id, b.title``` or that with "as".
So yes technically I could parse the query and get the columns however I don't think its trivial to do that unless you know of some commercially available free SQL parsers.

Comment: There is no need to parse the columns from the query. I will add an answer with an example.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256046/discussion-between-humblecoder-and-mahmoud-ben-hassine).

Answer (score 0):

Since you are passing the sql query as a job parameter and you know the columns upfront, then you can create a step-scoped header callback that you dynamically configure with the columns. Something like:

```
String columns = "id,name";
JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder()
   .addString("columns", columns)
   .addString("query", "select " + columns.split(",") + " from ...")
   .toJobParameters();
```

Then define a step-scoped header callback:

```
@Bean
@StepScope
public FlatFileHeaderCallback headerCallback(@Value("#{jobParameters['columns']}") String columns) {
        String[] columnsArray = columns.split(",");
        return writer -> writer.write(""); // write columns as needed
    }
```

This callback can be set on the writer. The reader can be configured with the `query` job parameter.

With that in place, there is no need to introspect the columns from the result set in the mapper and share them via a holder object with the writer.

EDIT: based on comments:

> The query and the report schedule is provided by the user and is stored in the database and a report is scheduled for this template having the given query`.

In that case, the better way would be to create a preparation tasklet step that extracts the columns from the query (ie the code that is currently based on the resultset's metadata in the mapper), and put the columns in the job execution context. Then you can configure the header callback to get the info from the job execution context and not job parameters.

Comment: I do not know the columns separately like you have mentioned : ```String columns = "id,name";```. To get the columns I ll have to parse the query.

Comment: Ok now I understand better, this could have been part of the initial question, but no problem. I updated the answer with how I would approach this. I think the issue now is that the chunk-oriented step is doing too much. I suggest to extract the column introspection task in a separate step.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I have now updated the question with the complete job config.